# Centroid of a triangle and its center of mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass

I am trying to find proof of fact that the centroid of a triangle is the center of mass of a triangle. But in every video or article I see, it's just saying that it's true, and not proving it. I wanna see proof to understand why it is so. Can someone prove it but without integrals, because I don't know them yet.

Comment: @Jonas it's not a homework question, I am just interested in it, and I am asking

Comment: What is your definition of “centroid”?

Comment: centroid is the point where medians cross with each other

Comment: presumably, you are assuming a uniform mass-density

Comment: What is your definition of “center of mass” without using an integral?

Comment: Whether a question is considered “homework-and-exercises” on this site is unrelated to whether it is actual homework.

Comment: Your definition of centroid is not [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid)’s. Wikipedia defines it as an arithmetic mean over all the points, which makes it an integral.

Comment: @G.Smith Actually, their definition [is on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_a_triangle).

Comment: @Sandejo That’s not the definition; that’s the *result* for a triangle. The centroid of *any* shape is defined at the beginning of the article. There is not a definition for each different shape.

Answer (score 3):

1. Draw a dotted line from one vertex to the middle of the opposite side.
2. Now divide the triangle into infinitesimally wide strips parallel to the opposite side.
3. The dotted line divides each strip in half, so the masses of each strip will balance across the dotted line.
4. Hence, the masses of the two halves of the triangle will balance across the dotted line.
5. Therefore the CM of the triangle is somewhere on that dotted line.
6. Repeat the procedure with the other two vertex/edge pairs to convince yourself that the CM lies on all three vertex-to-mid-point lines. Hence the CM must be at the point of intersection. And that intersection **is** the centroid of the triangle,

[image]